# tikzpicture in exsheets solution

Tags: tikz-pgf, exsheets

I get problems with `\datavisualization` in an `exsheets` solution. I only get a small cross but not the parabola.

Has someone similar experience and can help me?

```
\begin{solution}[print]
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \datavisualization [school book axes, visualize as smooth line]
    data { x, y
      -1.5, 2.25
      -1, 1
      -.5, .25
      0, 0
      .5, .25
      1, 1
      1.5, 2.25
    };
   \end{tikzpicture}
\end{solution}
```

Comment: Can you extend your code into a complete little socument, please?

Comment: A short part of the document could be:

Comment: How can I write down the document?

Comment: Just edit your question. It is easier to start looking for an answer if we can just copy your code and compile without having to complete the code ourselves.

Answer (score 1):

I use instead of data visualization only pgfplots. This works now very well.Here an example for a linear regression of  some measure points.

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
   \pgfplotsset{compat=newest, axis lines = middle}
    \begin{axis}[
    ymin=0, ymax =4, 
    xmin=0, xmax = 10,
    x=1cm, y=2cm,
    grid={both},
    xlabel={Auslenkung $s$ in cm},
    ylabel={Kraft $F$ in N}
    ]
    \addplot[only marks] table[row sep=\\]{
        X Y\\
        0.0 0.00\\
        1.0 0.42\\
        2.0 0.79\\
        3.0 1.22\\
        4.0 1.57\\
        5.0 1.99\\
        6.0 2.40\\
        7.0 2.59\\
        8.0 2.81\\
        9.0 3.00\\
    };
    \addplot table[row sep=\\,
    y={create col/linear regression={y=Y}}] % compute a linear regression from the
    %input table
    {
        X Y\\
        0.0 0.00\\
        1.0 0.42\\
        2.0 0.79\\
        3.0 1.22\\
        4.0 1.57\\
        5.0 1.99\\
        6.0 2.40\\
    };
     \end{axis}   
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Regards